# Why I get nothing back from node.js server on android

Tags: android, sockets

I'm developing a android app with Socket connections. I followed a tutorial on the Internet with a sample server and android client (http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.nl/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html).

the tutorial worked perfectly.

But I'm trying to connect to a Node.js socket io server with same android client contact. I can send messages with it but I can not received while the server sends a ping every second.

Why its not working? 
what am I doing wrong?

The Node.js socket io server is working fine, the iPhone version of the app can send and receive.

All ports are open.

Can someone help me please? Thank u!

**Source**

TCPClient.java

```
 public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "*ip-addres*"; //your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {

                //send the message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;

                }


                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");


            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }}
```

ChatActivity.java

```
    public class ChatActivity extends Activity{
 private ListView mList;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private TCPClient mTcpClient;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

        //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
        mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // connect to the server
        new connectTask().execute("");

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String message = editText.getText().toString();

                //add the text in the arrayList
                arrayList.add("c: " + message);

                //sends the message to the server
                if (mTcpClient != null) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
                }

                //refresh the list
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
            // from server was added to the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Node JS Server

```
    var net = require('net');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var colorize = require('colorize');
var cconsole = colorize.console;

var clients = [];
var count = 0;

var messages = [];

function create_id()
{
        return count += 1;
}

setInterval(function()
{
        for(i = 0; i < clients.length; i++)
        {
                var client = clients[i];

                var params = {};
                params.type = "ping";

                if(client.socket.write(JSON.stringify(params)))
                {
                        console.log("ping send");
                }
                else
                {
                        clients.splice(i, 1);
                }
        }
}, 1000);

var server = net.createServer(function( socket )
{      
        cconsole.log("#red[Client connected to the server with ip: " + socket.remoteAddress+"]");

        socket.on("error",function(error)
        {
                console.log("error" + error);
        });

        socket.on("close",function()
        {
                cconsole.log("#red[Client has disconnected]");
        });

        socket.on("data",function(data)
        {        
                try
                {
                        var packet = JSON.parse(data);

                        if(packet.type == "register")
                        {
                                var client = [];

                                client.socket = socket;
                                client.clientID = create_id();
                                client.username = packet.username;

                                messages[packet.username] = [];

                                clients.push(client);

                                var params = {};

                                params.type = "register";
                                params.clientID = client.clientID;

                                socket.write(JSON.stringify(params));

                                console.log("Registered client : " + params.clientID);         
                        }

                        if(packet.type == "online")
                        {
                                var params = {};
                                var identifiers = [];

                                for(i = 0; i < clients.length; i++)
                                {

                                        identifiers.push(clients[i].clientID);
                                }

                                params.type = "online";
                                params.clients = identifiers;

                                socket.write(JSON.stringify(params));
                        }

                        if(packet.type == "message")
                        {
                                var client = packet.sender;
                                var recipient = packet.recipient

                                for(i = 0; i < clients.length; i++)
                                {
                                        if(clients[i].clientID.toString() == recipient.toString())
                                        {
                                                var params = {}

                                                params.type = "message";
                                                params.sender = packet.sender;
                                                params.recipient = packet.recipient;
                                                params.message = packet.message;

                                                clients[i].socket.write(JSON.stringify(params));

                                                console.log("Wrote message " + params.message + " from sender " + params.sender +  " to recipient " + recipient)
                                                return;
                                        }
                                }
                                        console.log("Recipient was not valid");                        
                        }
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                        cconsole.log(e.message);
                }
        });    
});

server.listen(8124,"<Server IP>", function()
{      
        //'listening' listener
        cconsole.log('Server is listening for incoming connections');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Endian-ness of your client and server programs. Your Android app may be sending things in Network Byte Order (Big Endian) while your server is expecting them in Little Endian.

If this is the case, you should make both of your clients transmit with the same byte order, e.g. by using a specific serializer that deals in the correct byte order.

Comment: The server can receive and understand my data. But not receiving,  is it for sending and receiving different byte order?

Comment: Try to send a numeric value to the server from the Android app and put a breakpoint or log message in the server application displaying that value. If the server reads the correct number, Endian-ness is not your issue.

Comment: Ja the server can read my message , and server sending message back but the android client can`t receive the message.

Comment: i have the same problem. But when the server is stopped, all messages are getting as a single one and then closing the connection

Answer (score 0):

```
while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();
                // check if you get a message here..

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }
```

try to log from the comment to see if you actually get something